# Smart pagination algorithm that works with local data cache

Tags: algorithm, pagination

This is a problem I have been thinking about for a long time but I haven't written any code yet because I first want to solve some general problems I am struggling with. This is the main one.

### Background

A single page web application makes requests for data to some remote API (which is under our control). It then stores this data in a local cache and serves pages from there. Ideally, the app remains fully functional when offline, including the ability to create new objects.

### Constraints

- Assume a server side database of products containing +- 50000 products (50Mb)
- Assume no db type, we interact with it via REST/GraphQL interface
- Assume a single product record is < 1kB
- Assume a max payload for a resultset of 256kB
- Assume max 5MB storage on the client
- Assume search result sets ranging between 0 ... 5000 items per search

### Challenge

The challenge is to define a stateless but (network) efficient way fetch pages from a result set so that it is deterministic which results we will get.

### Example

In traditional paging, when getting the next 100 results for some query using this url:

```
https://example.com/products?category=shoes&firstResult=100&pageSize=100
```

the search result may look like this:

```
{
  "totalResults": 2458,
  "firstResult": 100,
  "pageSize": 100,
  "results": [
    {"some": "item"},
    {"some": "other item"},
    // 98 more ...
  ]
}
```

The problem with this is that there is no way, based on this information, to get *exactly* the objects that are on a certain page. Because by the time we request the next page, the result set may have changed (due to changes in the DB), influencing which items are part of the result set. Even a small change can have a big impact: one item removed from the DB, that happened to be on page 0 of the result set, will change what results we will get when requesting all subsequent pages.

### Goal

I am looking for a mechanism to make the definition of the result set independent of future database changes, so if someone was looking for shoes and got a result set of 2458 items, he could actually fetch all pages of that result set reliably even if it got influenced by later changes in the DB (I plan to not really delete items, but set a removed flag on them, for this purpose)

### Ideas so far

I have seen a solution where the result set included a `"pages"` property, which was an array with the first and last id of the items in that page. Assuming your IDs keep going up in number and you don't really delete items from the DB ever, the number of items between two IDs is constant. Meaning the app could get all items between those two IDs and always get the exact same items back. The problem with this solution is that it only works if the list is sorted in ID order... I need custom sorting options.

The only way I have come up with for now is to just send a list of all IDs in the result set... That way pages can be fetched by doing a `SELECT * FROM products WHERE id IN (3,4,6,9,...)`... but this feels rather inelegant...

Any way I am hoping it is not too broad or theoretical. I have a web-based DB, just no good idea on how to do paging with it. I am looking for answers that help me in a direction to learn, not full solutions.

Comment: I may be missing something but if the user has the ability to create new objects offline the indexes cannot be sequential (unless you have a different id for offline objects).

Comment: Normally people don't care about that and just fetch the items, how fast are your records updated so that becomes an issue?

Comment: @fpg1503 The system would be using a distributed ID generator that can work offline. So the client knows the ID the record will have even before inserting it.

Comment: What I am looking for is a way to capture a resultset in such a way that it is stable over time. The contents of individual items may change but I don't want the order of the items or which items are in the set to change. The reason for this is that I am presenting the items in a form of 'infinite scrolling list' that does it's utmost best to maintain the illusion that you have a list with all items in it even though only a small portion of it is actually on screen at the same time. Have a look at https://bridalapp.com/wedding-dresses to see an example. I want this to scale to 10.000+ items.

Comment: @fpg1503 I think only now I understand your remark about indexes not being sequential. You mean that it would not be guaranteed to go up only right? I guess you are right about that. I am currently using this hand-rolled generator: [ws.suid](http://download.github.io/suid/). The server hands out blocks of IDs to the clients that they can cache and use when they are offline. It increments over time but because of the caching, lower IDs could be used after higher IDs had already been used.  It seems I have more problems than I thought....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Versioning DB is the answer for resultsets consistency.
Each record has primary id, modification counter (version number) and timestamp of modification/creation. Instead of modification of record r you add new record with same id, version number+1 and sysdate for modification.

In fetch response you add DB request_time (do not use client timestamp due to possibly difference in time between client/server). First page is served normally, but you return sysdate as request_time. Other pages are served differently: you add condition like modification_time <= request_time for each versioned table.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes I though about this. It is a bit heavy-handed though. Ideally I would like a minimum of changes compared to a 'normal' data model. Changing DELETE operations to set a `removed` flag instead of actually deleting has a lot less impact. But you are right that this approach would work.

Comment: I decided to accept this because it's the best option I think. Still I think I will go with a less trict version, but using your idea for the timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

You can cache the result set of IDs on the server side when a query arrives for the first time and return a unique ID to the frontend. This unique ID corresponds to the result set for that query. So now the frontend can request something like `next_page` with the unique ID that it got the first time it made the query. You should still go ahead with your approach of changing `DELETE` operation to a `removed` operation because it would make sure that none of the entries from the result set it deleted. You can discard the result set of the query from the cache when the frontend reaches the end of the result set or you can set a time limit on the lifetime of the cache entry.

Comment: Yes this would work I think. Only downside here is that it requires the server to keep track of 'open' queries. Could be done with a cron job that deletes the state of queries that have not been used for x time. Thanks for your input!